# How to compute the integral $\int _{0}^{1}{\tan^{-1}\left(x\right) \over {1+x}}dx$

Tags: definite-integrals

How to compute the integral

$$\int_0^1 {\tan^{-1}\left(x\right) \over {1+x}}\,{\rm d}x$$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$\int_0^1 {{tan^{-1}x}\over {1+x}}dx=[tan^{-1}x\int {dx\over{1+x}}]_0^1-\int_0^1{log(1+x)\over{1+x^2}}dx={\pi\over 8}log2$

Putting $x=tan y$ in the 2nd integral

Answer (score 13):

Use the substitution $x=\frac{1-y}{1+y}$ so that $\mathrm{d}x=-\frac{2\mathrm{d}y}{(1+y)^2}$ and $\tan^{-1}(x)+\tan^{-1}(y)=\frac\pi4$.
$$
\begin{align}
\int_0^1\frac{\tan^{-1}(x)}{1+x}\,\mathrm{d}x
&=\int_0^1\frac{\frac\pi4-\tan^{-1}(y)}{\frac2{1+y}}\frac{2\mathrm{d}y}{(1+y)^2}\\
&=\int_0^1\frac{\frac\pi4-\tan^{-1}(y)}{1+y}\,\mathrm{d}y\\[4pt]
&=\frac\pi4\log(2)-\int_0^1\frac{\tan^{-1}(y)}{1+y}\,\mathrm{d}y\\
\end{align}
$$
Therefore,
$$
\int_0^1\frac{\tan^{-1}(x)}{1+x}\,\mathrm{d}x=\frac\pi8\log(2)
$$

Comment: Shouldn't the first integral in y be:
$\int_1^0\frac{\frac\pi4-\tan^{-1}(y)}{\frac2{1+y}}\frac{2\mathrm{d}y}{(1+y)^2}$ ??

Comment: @K.Rmth: except for the minus sign (in the $\mathrm{d}x$) and the reversal of the limits.

Comment: +1. I see the substitution $x=\frac{1-y}{1+y}$ made frequently with nasty integrals, sort of like the Weierstrass substitution. What sort of things do you look for in an integral to think about using your substitution?

Comment: @Joe: In this case, I started with $\tan^{-1}(x)+\tan^{-1}(y)=\frac\pi4$ and went from there. I can't recall which answer it was, but I've used this substitution before.

Comment: @robjohn Okay, thanks. I'm interested in learning more of the non-canonical tricks when it comes to integrals that come up from Putnam, USAMO, and such and I've seen the substitution a few times before.

Comment: Nice. UPVote $0$k.

Comment: @Joe: another nice thing about this substitution, that is not used here, is that not only does $\frac{\mathrm{d}x}{1+x}=-\frac{\mathrm{d}y}{1+y}$, but also $\frac{\mathrm{d}x}{1+x^2}=-\frac{\mathrm{d}y}{1+y^2}$